# Using EluetherAPI GPT models for NLP tasks

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

EluetherAPI released many GPT models based on the PILE dataset, which is equivalent to original GPT models. As they are trained on a larger dataset, we can perform multiple NLP tasks on the same model without retraining the model, with just a few prompts, or by providing some context using few-shot learning.

I am trying to achieve the same. But the problem is the return text is sometimes too large or too short. Here is my example code:

```
generator = pipeline('text-generation', model='EleutherAI/gpt-neo-1.3B', device=0)
prompt= """[Original]: The diplomatic spat came days after France cut the number of visas it issues for citizens of Algeria and other North African countries.
[Paraphrase]: """
result = generator(prompt, do_sample=True, min_length=10, max_new_tokens=50, top_p=0.9, temperature=1)
```

the result gave me this:

```
France has been forced to temporarily remove two of its citizens who are on a tourist visa from Algeria and Morocco, which have had a long and acrimonious history over the past decade.
[Original]: The two visa holders, who
```

As you can see, it gives me a result with the input text included, I removed the input text, and it works fine but at the end, it still shows the [Original]: prompt. How to remove it and give the exact same results?

I tried multiple times, even providing it context, but it works fine sometime and sometime not. I even tried few-shot learning with data as:

```
"""[Original]: Algeria recalled its ambassador to Paris on Saturday and closed its airspace to French military planes a day later after the French president made comments about the northern Africa country. 
[Paraphrase]: Last Saturday, the Algerian government recalled its ambassador and stopped accepting French military airplanes in its airspace. It happened one day after the French president made comments about Algeria.
###
[Original]: President Macron was quoted as saying the former French colony was ruled by a "political-military system" with an official history that was based not on truth, but on hatred of France.
[Paraphrase]: Emmanuel Macron said that the former colony was lying and angry at France. He also said that the country was ruled by a "political-military system".
###
[Original]: The diplomatic spat came days after France cut the number of visas it issues for citizens of Algeria and other North African countries.
[Paraphrase]: Diplomatic issues started appearing when France decided to stop granting visas to Algerian people and other North African people.
###
[Original]: After a war lasting 20 years, following the decision taken first by President Trump and then by President Biden to withdraw American troops, Kabul, the capital of Afghanistan, fell within a few hours to the Taliban, without resistance.
[Paraphrase]:""
```

I want to know if is there any way to pass the end_sequence so that it will stop generating after that, also the parameters top_p and temperature to get good results.

Answer (score 3):

Your few-shot learning approach is good, but you will need to use a specific parameter in the text generation pipeline called `eos_token_id`: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.25.1/en/main_classes/text_generation#transformers.GenerationMixin.generate

This `eos_token_id` should be the token equivalent of `###`.
This id depends on the tokenizer you are using. The tokenizer used behind the hood by `EleutherAI/gpt-neo-1.3B` is the GPT-2 tokenizer: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/gpt2#transformers.GPT2Tokenizer

When tokenized with the GPT-2 tokenizer, `###` returns `21017`.

So you should set `eos_token_id=21017`, and it will stop the generation once the `###` sequence is met.

Comment: thank you so much for you suggestion Julien, I tried the token 21017 and it worked, I am now able to get the results but results sometimes are not good, does the performance depends on the sample dataset or what should be the ideal value for top_p and temperature best for paraphrasing?

Comment: My pleasure @DevPy. You can try to play with temperature and top_p, but unfortunately in my experience paraphrasing does not work so well with small models like GPT-Neo 1.3B. In my opinion you start obtaining good results with GPT-J only, nothing below that...

Comment: Oh ok, since I am on limited on hardware and the project is small scale so going to paid api is not also a option.. So can I get the better result with little fine-tuning after train it with 500-1k example sentences? also if I train it for paraphrase will it continue working same for other nlt or text generation or it can then only be used for paraphrase??

Comment: That's 2 good questions and it's really hard to know without testing it... Intuitively I would say that even with 1k examples the result will still be poor, but I do encourage you to see for yourself as I might be wrong.

Comment: thanks Julien, I will definitely try that, one more question digging up in my mind, is there any parameter so we can remove producing duplicate, like sometime paraphrase returns exact same sentence given in input, I also tried increasing repetition_penalty but still sometime it occurs!

Comment: Unfortunately there is not. The best thing you can try is to increase top p or temperature...

Comment: ok thanks for answering all my question, my last doubt and it will help to increase the performance, do you know any resources where I can get atleast 20GB of RAM to use for sometime, so I can just load the 2.7B model and pickle it, so that size is reduced when I load it on my local so that it can fit it in my 16GB RAM?? I just read somewhere that pickling reduce the load time memory consumption, or any link to pickled version of 2.7B model, that would be really helpful!

Comment: @DevPy can you please share your code? I still have a problem with the EOS token.

Comment: @JulienSalinas can you give me a code example?

Comment: @SaeedRahmani result = generator(prompt, do_sample=True, min_length=10, max_new_tokens=50, top_p=0.9, temperature=1, eos_token_id=21017)